# How to upgrade Fedora from 20 to 25

Tags: fedora, system-installation, upgrade

My upgrade from Fedora 20 to 25 is long overdue. I have just received the DVD from the Linux shop, and have daily backups of my home directory and `/etc` made with fwbackups.

Where can I find a guide to the easiest way to do this, if possible without disturbing my data, email and other settings I have already?

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading#Upgrading_from_End_of_life_releases

Answer (score 6):

Fedora doesn't have a DVD-based upgrade process; updates are started using `fedup` or `dnf system-upgrade`. We * test updates from the previous release and the release before that — so, from F23 or F24 to F25, but not from F20 to F25 directly.

Since you have data backed up, and the DVD in-hand, the easiest way may just be to do a fresh install of F25 and then put your information back. (I usually make `/home` a separate partition, to make this easier when I decide to do it.)

We do have some suggestions for upgrading from old releases — see [Upgrading from End of Life releases](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading#Upgrading_from_End_of_life_releases) on the Fedora wiki. The basic advice is to upgrade with `yum` to at least Fedora 21, and then `dnf system-upgrade` from there. You may have better results doing yum/dnf based upgrades all the way to F23 before doing `dnf system-upgrade` — or even going all the way to F25 that way.

The good news here is that we've worked to make `dnf system-upgrade` as painless as possible (often taking less than half an hour), so when your upgraded F25 system gets to end of life, going to F27 should be a piece of cake.

---

<sub>* I work on Fedora</sub>